# R How to get the difference between current and next row that matches certain condition?

Tags: r

I understand that the question seems bit confusing. One example could be,

```
                          Time        x
    2017-07-24 12:33:13.000000      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:14.000000      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:15.000000      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:16.000000      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:16.500000      1.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:17.000000      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:17.500000      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:18.500000      1.0
```

In R, I want to have another column that, for each row, compute difference between the time for the current row and the time for the next row where x is not 0. So the results look like this:

```
                          Time        x     diff
    2017-07-24 12:33:13.000000      0.0      3.5
    2017-07-24 12:33:14.000000      0.0      2.5
    2017-07-24 12:33:15.000000      0.0      1.5
    2017-07-24 12:33:16.000000      0.0      0.5
    2017-07-24 12:33:16.500000      1.0      0.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:17.000000      0.0      1.5
    2017-07-24 12:33:17.500000      0.0      1.0
    2017-07-24 12:33:18.500000      1.0      0.0
```

Thank you for answering in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the rows where "x == 1":

```
wh = which(dat$x == 1)
```

we can build a vector of indices of the nearest (forward) "1":

```
i = rep(wh, c(wh[1], diff(wh)))
```

And then subtract the respective "Time"s:

```
dat$Time[i] - dat$Time
#Time differences in secs
#[1] 3.5 2.5 1.5 0.5 0.0 1.5 1.0 0.0
```

"dat" is:

```
dat = structure(list(Time = structure(c(1500888793, 1500888794, 1500888795, 
1500888796, 1500888796.5, 1500888797, 1500888797.5, 1500888798.5
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), x = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("Time", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 8L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a [Rolling join](https://www.r-bloggers.com/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/) from the data.table() library can help.

Here's my solution:

First, let's set up your example data

```
library('data.table')

time <- as.POSIXct(c('2017-07-24 12:33:13.000000', '2017-07-24 12:33:14.000000', '2017-07-24 12:33:15.000000', '2017-07-24 12:33:16.000000', '2017-07-24 12:33:16.500000', '2017-07-24 12:33:17.000000', '2017-07-24 12:33:17.500000', '2017-07-24 12:33:18.500000'))

x <- c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

dat <- data.table(time, x)
```

Now, let's add a dummy column for the sake of the join:

```
dat[, key := 1]
```

Subset the data to just the x = 1 columns into a new table

```
ones <- dat[x==1, list(time, key, ref.time = time)]
```

Notice that I also create a `ref.time` column.  That's for performing the subtraction.

Set keys for the rolling join

```
setkey(dat, key, time)
setkey(ones, key, time)
```

Now do the join.  This answers the question "what is the nearest x==1 row to any given row in the original data"

```
joined.dat <- ones[dat, roll = -Inf]
```

Compute the difference you seek

```
joined.dat[, diff := ref.time - time]
```

Final output:

```
                  time key            ref.time x     diff
1: 2017-07-24 12:33:13   1 2017-07-24 12:33:16 0 3.5 secs
2: 2017-07-24 12:33:14   1 2017-07-24 12:33:16 0 2.5 secs
3: 2017-07-24 12:33:15   1 2017-07-24 12:33:16 0 1.5 secs
4: 2017-07-24 12:33:16   1 2017-07-24 12:33:16 0 0.5 secs
5: 2017-07-24 12:33:16   1 2017-07-24 12:33:16 1 0.0 secs
6: 2017-07-24 12:33:17   1 2017-07-24 12:33:18 0 1.5 secs
7: 2017-07-24 12:33:17   1 2017-07-24 12:33:18 0 1.0 secs
8: 2017-07-24 12:33:18   1 2017-07-24 12:33:18 1 0.0 secs
```

Comment: Your answer can be a bit cleaner if you use `dplyr` or `tidyverse` or use `data.table` more efficiently. But I like the idea. Cheers. +1

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and feedback!  Does anything specific jump out about how the data.table usage could be more efficient?  This did feel a bit cumbersome as I was putting it together, but I wasn't sure how to streamline it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Base R and vectorization:

```
a <- c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 17, 20, 23, 34)
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1)
```

By hand, the answer should be this:

```
c <- c(9, 7, 4, 0, 2, 0, 14, 11, 0)
```

Create a vector of which values in b are the 'pivots'. We also attach 0 as a starting point:

```
pivots <- c(0, which(b != 0))
```

Finally, repeat those pivots as many times are there are between a value of `0` and the next `1`.

```
vec <- rep(a[pivots], times = diff(pivots)
identical(c, vec - a)
```

If you wanted to turn this into a function that takes a `values` vector/column and a `pivots` vector/column you can do something like this:

```
diffToNextPivot <- function(values, pivots) {
  pivots <- c(0, which(pivots != 0))
  vec <- rep(values[pivots], times = diff(pivots))
  vec - values
}

myDataFrame$diff <- diffToNextPivot(myDataFrame$Time, myDataFrame$x)
```